# Why is strip giving an unexpected result for the given string?

Tags: python

I have a simple string as follows :

```
str = "id : c40d675f-19a9-4d40-9c6f-223eddafc81d"
```

Expected output :

> c40d675f-19a9-4d40-9c6f-223eddafc81**d**

What I tried ?

```
print(str.strip('id : '))
```

What I get :

> c40d675f-19a9-4d40-9c6f-223eddafc81

I am not able to understand, why is the last character '**d**' from the end of string is stripped away? When I tried replacing the character '**d**' with other alphabets, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to do this :

```
str.split(":")[1].strip()
```

`strip` removes any possible combination of characters provided as its argument from both the start and end of the string. Here, the argument being `'id : '`, it strips `'id : '` from the beginning and `'d'` (one of the possible combinations of the string `'id : '`) from the end of the string.

Comment: That's horribly inefficient, in this case, tho. If we assume the structure to remain the same `str[5:]` is far more appropriate.

Comment: What do you suggest then ? Your answer doesn't include a solution tho. If you see correctly, I mentioned "Maybe you wanted to do this", not "I would do this". @zwer

Comment: And why do you assume that this won't work in other cases, this solution will always report correctly what is there after the string `id : `. @zwer

Comment: @Jarvis - I suggested how to improve your answer as you were already providing a solution while my answer was dealing with 'why it happens'.

Comment: this answer didn't pointing out why OP got unexpected result even though it works

Comment: @Jarvis  I agree with zwer. You can improve your answer, it is accepted as the answer but doesn't mean it is a good one

Comment: Just did to the best of my extent. Lift your downvote now please. @HaifengZhang

Answer (score 3):

Because `strip()` takes a set of characters to remove from both sides of the string. If you have written: `str.strip("i18d")` it would remove `81d` from the end and `id` from the beginning.

Comment: thanks. Yes I was giving 'id' as a parameter to strip as well, which had character 'd'. I should have got it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this link should help you.

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm

look at the return value that strip gives

Answer (score 0):

**strip([chars]):**

> The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped

Be aware, it removes all combinations of the characters you provided!

```
>>> str.lstrip("id :")
'c40d675f-19a9-4d40-9c6f-223eddafc81d'
```

`lstrip()` returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning of the string

***Alternatively***, You can use `str.replace("id : ", "", 1)`, specify that replace the 1st occurrence of "id : " to empty string

Answer (score 0):

`strip()` strips the leading or trailing characters of the string off of every character in the sequence.

```
>>> 'abcadb'.strip('ab')
'cad'

>>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')
'example'
```